# Is there a gem/plugin that will populate a database with test data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rubygems

is there a gem or plugin that will populate a database with test data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ever, Ryan Bates has a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database) on this very subject that covers using the [Faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org/) and [Populator](http://populator.rubyforge.org/) gems.

Answer (score 2):

For testing, I'm a fan of [thoughtbot's factory girl](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/factory_girl).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Fixtures in Rails. It comes with the standard Rails kit.

See Also: [A Guide To Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) - see section 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I think [Red Gate's SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) will do that. I use their SQL Prompt product. Pretty popular product it seems. Even [Scott Gu blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/22/Red_2D00_Gate-SQL-Query-Intellisense-Tool-_2800_Free-Download_2900_.aspx) about them.

[edit] oh, unless you meant for rails ... 8|